# Windows 7 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I can't load my Windows 7 (even safe mode), because it crashes, restarts and gives me blue screen of error: `0x0000007b` like this one:

[image]

I have Ubuntu installed. What should I do, please help me. It happened after I, like an idiot, opened file which had a virus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot into Ubuntu and copy all your data that you need/want. After that you can download [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/shop/download-windows-7) and then burn it to a disc, and install it.

---

If you don't have/know your product key: Download a keyfinder from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ekeyfinder/), then write down your Windows 7 product key.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many articles](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=DoE&channel=fs&gl=uk&sa=X&ei=IinIToKnN4Ke8gPF6qlc&ved=0CBoQvwUoAQ&q=7b%20windows%207%20bsod&spell=1) online helping with the 7B BSOD, here's [one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/x0000007b-blue-screen-after-safe-mode-boot-driver/b6f8aa09-4b22-498c-b16b-0c39229caee7)

My recommendation would be to boot Ubuntu, save everything that you need (documents etc) from the windows drive and then reinstall Windows 7 to avoid any problems.

Comment: I don't have disk to reinstall Windows-7.

Comment: @hey: You should probably get started on that, considering they are **free**.