# BIOS Error after update

Tags: windows, boot, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Windows 7 0x0000007B](https://superuser.com/questions/359326/windows-7-0x0000007b)

After updating the BIOS I've received this error, and I can't enter Windows now.

How can I fix this problem? Is there a recovery or patch?

[image]

> Laptop: Toshiba l300
>
> BIOS: Insyde H2O

Comment: here's an article that explains a lot of different things to try for fixing a STOP 7B: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm

Comment: @Anas AbuDayah Enter the bios and load defaults, save changes on exit of bios.