# WIN7 constant BSOD 0x7B on boot, not producing any dump files where to go from here?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 0x0000007B](https://superuser.com/questions/359326/windows-7-0x0000007b)

So my one win 7 pc has been getting a BSOD on boot (roughly a sec after load screen starts) after a power failure. The complete stop code is

*0x0000007B (0x80786B58, 0xC0000034,0x00000000,0x00000000)*

I've searched for quite a while now on the net and it seems like most people gave up after gettting 0x7B and no dump files.

What I've tried so far:

- **startup repair** - reports it cannot repair computer automatically. BadPatch is reported somewhere in a problem signature contained in the problem details.
- **startup repair with a WIN 7 CD** - also fails, I can't recall what the error was, but it was not the same as the error produced with the start up tool shipped with the version of WIN 7 installed on my machine (I think the text had something ACL-ish contained in it)
- **used a boot disk (Hiren's boot iso)** - I used it to enable the CrashDump registry key and then after BSOD, read the HDD's dump locations but it was empty. Note, I'm quite sure the registry keys I edited are the correct ones, since the reboot on BSOD option was enabled by default and after I changed the regkey controlling this functionalitty to 0 the BSOD stayed after I booted again.
- **check disk** - works and returns no problems, also it seems I'm able to access all my files on the HDD.
- **mem test** - works and returns no errors

So I'm not sure what else I can do to figure out what is the problem here. I read somewhere that you can use WINDBG to remote debug another PC, but I'm not sure if this is possible since the OS isn't even loaded yet?

Also the last driver change I made on the system was installing a video driver, but I had no problems with it and were able to reboot several times until the power outage happened and the BSOD appeared.

Any help or guidance for a way to DEBUG this problem would really be appreciated (I'm not really that keen to try a whole bunch of random fixes, I'd rather try and narrow down the problem first).

UPDATE
I know I can copy all the data on the HDD and do a clean install, but I was hoping someone could provide some guidance with debugging the issue to see if I can solve the problem without doing a clean install.

Comment: Do you get an `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` text?

Comment: Restore from backup. :)  Seriously though (because why do backups right?), you're best bet is probably to just boot a LiveCD, get all your data and reinstall.

Comment: @techie007 yes sorry it seems it is an duplicate, the photo shown on this defect is what I see with my pc, except for the number that appears after the 7B stop code. Unfortunately I don't have a restore point or backup to restore to. I know that I'm probably going to re-install windoz, but I really want to see how far I can go into debugging this for the sake of learning something